# Coded UI doesn't work in windows 10 and Visual studio 2015

Tags: automated-testing, visualstudio, coded-ui-tests, windows

When I try to record and play a window app like calculator it does not record while it works for a web site and browsers. 
My windows version is 10 
and Visual Studio version is 15.
It says you require to reboot your computer and start the recorder again, but after rebooting the problem is still the same.

Comment: I have the same issue runing Windows 10 with VS 2015. All test faled with  BrowserWindow.Launch(vUrl), i think mabye it can be IE issue ??